# updating table view with data in array?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am creating a Ipad with two view controllers. One view controller is `FirstViewController` and the other is `SecondViewController`. In `FirstViewController`, I fill an array with numbers. Now in my `SecondViewCOntroller`, I have a table view. I want to put the array that I created in `FirstViewController` into my `SecondViewController` table view? How do I do this? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the NSArray object in the SecondViewController, you could do this by means of a delegate. A delegate is an instance variable that contains the pointer to the delegate, in this case the FirstviewController. Then in FirstViewController you add a property for the NSArray if its an instance variable, and call delegate.someArrayName in the secondviewController

Comment: So what you're saying is that in my FirstViewController. I have a variable like this: FirstViewController *firstViewVariable; then add the property. Then call it in SecondViewController? I'm a little confused, is this right?

Comment: @serge2487 yeah my answer is not really easy if you do this for the first time.. eh you know what a delegate is and how to use that?

Comment: i am using delegate and datasource methods for my tableview. I know how to fill my table but only if its all done in my SecondViewcontroller. I think so lol.

Comment: Well you add a variable to the SecondViewController that contains the delegate.. "id delegate;"   "@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;" in the header     "@synthesize delegate;" in the source file           and then when you create SecondViewController you do this: secondViewControllerVar.delegate = FirstViewController;      and then you can go from there, as you can access the FirstViewController in the secondViewController

Answer (score 1):

This approach breaks MVC. You can't have data array as an instance variable in your `FirstViewController`. You'd have to store data in some other class (the M part of MVC). You fill that M part from `FirstViewController` (the V part) and then access that filled M part from `SecondViewController`. This way you won't be dependent on how those two controllers relate to each other (parent/child or siblings or whatever other hierarchy you may think of).

The most simple approach I can think of is storing serialized array in a plist file. Storing the file in first and accessing it in the second view controller.

Comment: i see. how would store it in a plist. does that mean the array can't change? Because I would be changing its content pretty often.

Comment: You can change the array. You'd just overwrite plist contents. There are convenience methods for this. Just check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward approach will be to create a property on SecondViewController.h like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

and in SecondViewController.m, put:

```
@synthesize yourArray;
```

At this point you have created a property on SecondViewController. Now, when you are about to open Second View Controller, just create its instance and do something like following:

```
secondViewController.yourArray = array;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController];
```